# Printing multiple dictionary keys on one line

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, printing, line

I have this code:

```
my_dict = {'key1':'roger','key2':'bootsma'}
print (my_dict['key1']), (my_dict['key2'])
```

But i does not seem to be able to print on one line as one would suspect. It does print one key but cannot print a key after that on same line.

Comment: That's not currently valid syntax, as you're missing a closing parenthesis. Also, the second `my_dict['key1']` is **outside** the call to `print`.

Comment: Sorry it is actually like this:

Comment: my_dict = {'key1':'roger','key2':'bootsma'}
print (my_dict['key1']), (my_dict['key1'])

Comment: 1. Then [edit] the question. 2. That only solves the first problem I mention. Did you mean to pass two arguments to `print`?

Comment: sorry rather new here, i changed the syntax, what i am trying to achieve is to have it print roger bootsma but it only prints roger

Comment: Then why do you end the `print` function call by closing the parentheses after the first parameter?

Comment: I tried this: print (my_dict['key1','key2']) and this: print (my_dict['key1'],['key2']) but both gave an error so now i don't know what to do

Comment: Only the first one would give you an error. I think you want `print(my_dict['key1'], my_dict['key1'])`, i.e. passing two separate things to `print`, both dictionary values accessed by key. I'd strongly recommend an introductory tutorial - http://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Comment: print (my_dict['key1'], my_dict['key2']) you are right, this solved it, thank you a lot, one more question, how do i mark this question as solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generally acceptable answer to your question is this:

```
print('{} {}'.format(my_dict['key1'], my_dict['key2']))
```

Some other possibilities:

```
print('%s %s' % (my_dict['key1'], my_dict['key2']))
# or
print(' '.join(my_dict.values()))

# or    
print(my_dict['key1'], end='')
print(my_dict['key2'])
```

Comment: print (my_dict['key1'], my_dict['key2']) this solved it :)